# Texture paint doesn't work in 3D

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Texture paint doesn't work. Worked just fine but somewhere after using stencil texture (possible reason?) it broke.

I can paint in 2d mode but 3d is a no go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Was frustrated and wrote without thinking. Thank you for editing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like masking is enabled, this button:

[image]

Try to disable it

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem rather then a solution.

I just appended objects into a new file.

1. Create a new blender file
2. Go to *File > Append*, choose original file with which you had a problem
3. Go to *Object* folder and choose everything.